# How to make a batch file command wait for powershell script to finish

Tags: windows-10, batch-file

I run two commands in a batch file, but I need the `del` command to wait for the powershel script to be executed.

I tried to use the command from the link below, without success:
[the-batch-script-to-wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59546857/calling-a-powershell-script-from-batch-script-but-need-the-batch-script-to-wait)

Batch file:

```
powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \"D:\z_Batchs e Scripts\Batchs\Normaliza_LUFS\ArqsNorms_LUFS_pass.ps1\" -_vLUF %_vLUF%'"

del /q "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\Logs_LUFS\LOG_*.*"
```

How to make the `del` command run only after the powershell script finishes?

Comment: Why not move the del command to the powershell script? the %username% would become $env:username

Comment: @LPChip It worked. Put it as an answer so I can vote on it, ok?

Comment: @LPChip Thanks, LPChip.

Comment: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to simply move the del command to the powershell script instead.

You can substitude %username% for $env:username in your script.